# Group data by week in a month and get the start and end date

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I want to group data in week in a month how do that? 
here's the example data

```
date            point1  point2
"2020-03-01"    1000    2000
"2020-03-02"    1000    2000
"2020-03-03"    1000    2000
"2020-03-04"    1000    2000
"2020-03-05"    1000    2000
"2020-03-06"    1000    2000
"2020-03-07"    1000    2000
"2020-03-08"    1000    2000
"2020-03-09"    1000    2000
"2020-03-10"    1000    2000
"2020-03-11"    1000    2000
"2020-03-12"    1000    2000
"2020-03-13"    1000    2000
"2020-03-14"    1000    2000
"2020-03-15"    1000    2000
"2020-03-16"    1000    2000
"2020-03-17"    1000    2000
"2020-03-18"    1000    2000
"2020-03-19"    1000    2000
"2020-03-20"    1000    2000
"2020-03-21"    1000    2000
"2020-03-22"    1000    2000
"2020-03-23"    1000    2000
"2020-03-24"    1000    2000
"2020-03-25"    1000    2000
"2020-03-26"    1000    2000
"2020-03-26"    1000    2000
"2020-03-27"    100     2000
"2020-03-28"    1000    2000
"2020-03-29"    1000    2000
"2020-03-30"    1000    2000
```

I want to grouping by week in a month and get the start and end date how i do that?

I was trying using laravel, the code is like below

```php
$startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->get('start_date')));
$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->get('end_date')));

$transactions = $this->transaction
                ->select(
                    DB::raw("date_trunc('WEEK',(date + interval '1 day'))- interval '1 day' AS week"),
                    DB::raw('sum("point1" + "point2") total')
                )
                ->groupBy('week')
                ->whereDate('date', '>=', $startDate)
                ->whereDate('date', '<=', $endDate)
                ->get();
```

the code above is gonna sum the next week in next month, as example date 29-03-2020 is continuing to 2020-04-04 and I dont want to do that, i just want to end in the last date in month (2020-03-31)

**What i expenting is**

```
start_date  end_date    total
2020-03-01  2020-03-07  21000
2020-03-08  2020-03-14  21000
2020-03-15  2020-03-21  21000
2020-03-22  2020-03-28  21000
2020-03-29  2020-03-31  21000
```

Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The total data remains under the where condition, the start of the week and the end of the week that do not match the where condition.
You should use php to edit the `start_date` value of the first week in the result and the `end_date` value of the last week's in the result

```
$transactions[0]->start_date = $startDate ? $startDate : $transactions[0]->start_date;
$transactions[$transactions->count() - 1]->end_date = $endDate ? $endDate : $transactions[$transactions->count() - 1];
```